# Screen display for individual use/ projector viewing

Tags: apache-flex, screen

I am building a learning product(in flex/flash) that will get used both by an individual on her desktop, and also by a instructor in a large room. The challenge is rooms, where this will be used, tend to be quite large- as big as 80-90 people and seating far from screen

I am not sure a single font size(12-14 font) will work for all- currently I have built it for "personal use" to use real-estate best and am hoping tweak slightly for "projector mode"- plan is to allow user to selectively pick and magnify various sections of the screen- is this a model that is done elsewhere- what are the best practices here?

Any thoughts on how to program for this?

Answer (score 1):

You should keep it down to only a few short lines of text and an image/video if you're presenting this on a projector. The fact is, 12-14px fonts are much too small for that application - you should use 24px and up. Consider that projectors will typically have lower resolutions than monitors and your display will be scaled down somehow, which usually renders small / thin text unreadable. You might want to design for a 1024x768 projector, and let your interface scale so the users see the same display (same proportions and positioning) on their computer - I caution you that if you must use raster images, use high enough resolution images that they don't see a pixelated mess on their high res screens.

A useful article on slide design can be found at http://www.thinkoutsidetheslide.com/articles/select_and_use_fonts.htm  and you can probably use the default templates in Powerpoint as a starting point for your layout. Don't shoehorn too much information into one screen!

Comment: Thanks- am planning my product to be used both on a self learning basis as well as intructor-led... not really a slide paradigm- am talking about animation, values generated during animation etc... I will not be able to stay at 24+ px to accomodate a wealth of information... key is this is not conceptual information where the slide acts as a reference- more simulation details that cannot be avoided

Comment: You're going to have to dumb down the display that you use for projection, perhaps only displaying a few of the real time data points and allowing the instructor to switch between different sets of data on the fly. The fact is, you just can't read smaller type if you're sitting in the back of the audience. It's fine for a personal display where you can adjust your viewing distance if necessary. A classroom or auditorium projector is not the appropriate place for a "wealth of information". It should be possible to come up with a useful way to do what you're doing, for sure. Good luck!